# Problem with LZO

Tags: c++, lzo

So I am trying to use LZO in my application. Here is how I have included it:

```
#include "lzoconf.h"
#include "lzodefs.h"
#include "lzo1x.h"
/* portability layer */
static const char *progname = NULL;
#define WANT_LZO_MALLOC 1
#define WANT_XMALLOC 1
#include "portab.h"
```

Then in the application I do:

```
if (lzo_init() != LZO_E_OK)
{
    printf("internal error - lzo_init() failed !!!\n");
    printf("(this usually indicates a compiler bug - try recompiling\nwithout optimizations, and enable '-DLZO_DEBUG' for diagnostics)\n");
    return 4;
}
```

It compiles ok. No errors or warnings during compilation.

When I try to run my application though, there are two errors:

```
/home/richard/client/src/portab.h:145: undefined reference to `__lzo_align_gap'
```

Which points at this line in portab.h:

```
if (__lzo_align_gap(p, (lzo_uint) sizeof(lzo_align_t)) != 0)
{
    printf("%s: C library problem: malloc() returned mis-aligned pointer!\n", progname);
    exit(1);
}
return p;
```

And in my application:

```
/home/richard/client/src/main.cc:108: undefined reference to `__lzo_init_v2'
```

Which points to:

```
if (lzo_init() != LZO_E_OK)
{
    printf("internal error - lzo_init() failed !!!\n");
    printf("(this usually indicates a compiler bug - try recompiling\nwithout optimizations, and enable '-DLZO_DEBUG' for diagnostics)\n");
    return 4;
}
```

I have all the header files inside my source directory:

```
config.h
lzo1x.h
lzoconf.h
lzodefs.h
miniacc.h
portab.h
portab_a.h
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am compiling my application in Ubuntu 10.10 in Anjuta ide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers is not enough, you need to link to the libraries. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how to link the library. It's not mentioned there.

Comment: @Richard: Does the Anjuta IDE have a tutorial that mentions anything about "library paths"? I have never heard of that IDE and am not a linux expert, but there should be some files with the extension `.a` somewhere in the LZO directory, right? Maybe in a directory called `lib`?

Comment: just a guess but is your LD_PATH setup up to point to the lzo library?, echo $LD_PATH for us?